# Shiny Server sockjs "Another Connection Still Open"

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shiny-server, sockjs

I have a shiny app which I am hosting on an AWS Ubuntu server. Suddenly, the session randomly crashes within about 1 minute of loading the app. It is not due to clicking any particular widget or selector.

The error I get in Network -> Response in the Firefox debugger is:

> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
>
> c[2010,"Another connection still open"]

I'm not sure what the "hhh.." line is but it could provide a clue to someone, so I've included it.

Method:  POST
File: xhr_streaming

I have rolled back my app version and database to a prior working version, and the error still occurs.

This error does not happen locally, or when debugging RStudio on the server.

My shiny-server version is v1.3.0.403.

Other sockjs issues appear to be resolved with a newer version of shiny-server, but it looks like mine is fairly up-to-date.

Any help regarding further debugging would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's in the `/var/log/shiny-server.log` file?

Comment: Sorry for the delay Jeff, I was abroad.  It looks like the offending lines all say the following:   `[INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mError getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.`  It's happening less frequently recently so I'm trying to think if anything has changed.